# Shell Script to transfer file to SFTP

Tags: linux, shell-script, sftp

I m trying to write shell script to transfer file from Linux to SFTP. I m not in Linux but was just trying by seeing youtube & reading. When I m trying to run that script it gets stuck & doesn't gives any successful message or error message but keeps on running neither I do see any file being placed in SFTP.

```
#!/bin/bash
lftp  <<_EOF_
open sftp://User:Password@Host Name -p port no.
lcd Directory in Linux
cd /
pwd
put file name (from Linux to SFTP)
exit
_EOF_
```

Can someone pls help if the script written is correct needs some changes?

Regards

Pankaj

Comment: You should edit your question and include what your script is supposed to do. One issue is most definitly all those placeholders you haven't replaced (`port no.`, `Host` etc.). Do you have an SFTP server to run this against?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to jump through these hoops instead of using a simple `scp` or even `rsync`?

Comment: "_I m trying [...] to transfer file from Linux to SFTP._" but "_I m not in Linux_". I don't understand how these two statements work together. Can you clarify please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.